# What are the differences between gitlab team and gitlab group?

Tags: gitlab

I'm using Gitlab 5.0 to manage my git repositories and I've never used github before Gitlab.

When I create a group, I see a new directory with this group name in /home/git/repositories.
But with team, no such thing is done.
Also, with group, I can create a project for the group and the assignments (for users of this group) is done automatically.

I can't see any other differences between **group** and **team** and I would like to understand that.

Thank you in advance and sorry for the bad English (I'm french),

Comment: Note: GitLab 6.0 (August 2013) replaces teams with "group membership". See [y edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15894795/6309)

Comment: Thank you for your edit. Now I'm going to upgrade to this version of Gitlab.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

GitLab 6.0 (August 2013, 22d)

See [commit 3bc4845](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/3bc4845874112242d6e885731c033ffe85ee98dd):

#### Feature: Replace teams with group membership

> We introduce **group membership** in 6.0 as a replacement for teams.
>   The old combination of groups and teams was confusing for a lot of people.
>   And when the members of a team where changed, this wasn't reflected in the project permissions.
>
> **In GitLab 6.0 you will be able to add members to a group with a permission level for each member**.
>   These group members will have access to the projects in that group.
>   Any changes to group members will immediately be reflected in the project permissions.
>   You can even have multiple owners for a group, greatly simplifying administration.

---

> Why do references to Teams still exist in GitLab 7 then? e.g. "Filter by Team"

- "**Team**" seems now (GitLab 6.x->7.x 2015) seems limited to a **project** (see for example [`features/project/team_management.feature`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/features/project/team_management.feature), and [`app/models/project_team.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/models/project_team.rb) or [`spec/models/project_team_spec.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/spec/models/project_team_spec.rb)).
  [A project can be part of a group](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/bd72b5bd32c64606a498066cadf9f765be059b9d/app/models/project_team.rb#L166-L168): see "[Gitlab API for all projects under group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31742822/6309)".
- "**Group**" references users, and can group multiple projects, (See [`features/groups.feature`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/features/groups.feature), [`app/models/group.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/models/group.rb), [`app/models/members/group_member.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/models/members/group_member.rb))

As a user, you are a first a member of a group, and have **roles** ('Reporter', 'Developer', ...) associated to a project (which makes you a member of that project, part of the "team" for that project).
No role, means "not a member of the team for a project".
See [`db/migrate/20140914145549_migrate_to_new_members_model.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/db/migrate/20140914145549_migrate_to_new_members_model.rb).

---

Answer for GitLab 5.x (before August 2013, 22d)

- **Group** is for grouping projects, similar to a folder (git repositories)
- **Team** is for grouping resources (people)

Those notions have been refined in [GitLab 4.2](http://blog.gitlab.org/gitlab-v4-dot-2-has-been-released/).

That allows you to manage authorization in a more convenient way, given permissions to a group of projects in one operation, and/or given permission to a group of people, referenced by their team.

GitLab 5.x no longer used Gitolite, but before 5.0, teams and groups are coming from [**Gitolite**](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/master-toc.html), and its [`gitolite.conf` configuration file](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/git-config.html).
This is where [team and groups](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/groups.html) were declared and associated in order to grant permission access.
Even without gitolite, the idea persists: managing the authorization through association between teams (of people) and groups (of projects).

Comment: Why do references to Teams still exist in GitLab 7 then? e.g. "Filter by Team"

Comment: I was wondering about this as well; I came across this Q for this exact question.

Comment: @PetervanArkel Team is for project (any user with role for that project), Group is for users. See my edit.

Comment: @VonC: Hi! I know this thread is quite old and i'm using version 9.3.9 but just wanted to know whether GitLab allows creating a team of devs and adding the team to a group/project? Say i have 10 people in a team and one leaves and another one joins the company. In such case, if i have a team named dev, i can simply remove the old user and add the new one to the team. That way, whichever group the team is part of, changes will automatically get reflected there.

Comment: @Technext Are you using CE or EE? With CE, we have to use a batch for provisioning groups (checking if a user is part of an LDAP group). With EE, you might not have to do that, because of LDAP group sync: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap-ee.html#use-cases

Comment: I am using CE and i am already using `user_filter` but that's on the AD side actually. I was looking for a feature that's on the GitLab UI side.

Comment: @Technext That is my point: on the GitLab side, there is no UI or synchronization feature. I have a Java program that will query every 15 minutes LDAP groups, and will query GitLab groups before reconciling the later with the folder, adding or removing users as needed.

Comment: Oh...got it now. Thanks for the idea @VonC. :)