# Notify all participants about merge request

Tags: gitlab

Is there a way to notify all gitlab project participants about new merge request, so they can review changes and vote? At the moment only a responsible person is notified and this is IMHO not very well team-oriented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this isn't supported, that would be a feature request to add to the ["feedback.gitlab.com" page](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general).

But consider also "[Notify only requester and not whole team on comment in merge request](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/3882662-notify-only-requester-and-not-whole-team-on-commen)":

> the whole team is notified via email when someone comments on a merge request. 
>   Please add the functionality to just notify the one who created the merge request to be notified

This is done since 5.3, which means a comment on a change request should notify a [group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15894795/6309), and not just the owner.

Comment: a hook for that would be nice: We'd like to post to campfire, whenever a new merge-request has been posted: Is there any way to extend the campfire-hooks to report on more than push-events?!

Comment: @mugwump I don't know, that could be a good question to ask here, or on the GitLab forum.