# How can I assign an existing repository to a gitlab group without cloning?

Tags: gitlab

When I try to select team member for a git repository in gitlab there I see no chance to assign a whole group. Is this a missing function? Or is it possible anyway?

I am using Gitlab 6.0

Comment: "team"? Are you using a GitLab 5.x? Teams were replaced by group membership in 6.0: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15894795/6309

Comment: I have added the version to my question. I have not written Team, but Team Member (under `Manage Access --> New Team Member`).