# git push failing on a local gitlab repo

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, git-push

1. I have installed Gitlab in `/home/myuser/gitlab`.

   1. I created a rep `testing`
   2. Following instructions, I added a remote `git@localhost:root/testing.git`

Here's my /home/myhome/.ssh/config file

```
Host mylocalhost
Hostname localhost
User git
IdentityFile /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
```

When I run `ssh mylocalhost`, I have the right message `Welcome to GitLab, Administrator!`. But then, I get the following input

```
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

Transferred: sent 3284, received 3480 bytes, in 0.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 7501.3, received 7949.0
debug1: Exit status 0`
```

and in my `GitLab` log

```
Started GET "/api/v3/internal/allowed?key_id=4&action=git-receive-pack&ref=_any&project=testing" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-07 16:48:00 +0100
```

Btw, each time I run some `git` command, I get the message

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname mylocalhost: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Someone has an idea ?

Update : running `gitlab-shell/bin/check` outputs

```
Check GitLab API access: OK
Check directories and files: 
    /Users/git/repositories: OK
```

and `bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production` outputs

```
System information
System:     Mac OS X 10.9
Current User:   myname
Using RVM:  yes
RVM Version:    1.21.7
Ruby Version:   2.0.0p195
Gem Version:    2.0.3
Bundler Version:1.3.5
Rake Version:   10.1.0

GitLab information
Version:    6.2.0.pre
Revision:   ea72f4f
Directory:  /Users/git/gitlab
DB Adapter: mysql2
URL:        http://localhost
HTTP Clone URL: http://localhost/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@localhost:some-project.git
Using LDAP: no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:    1.7.1
Repositories:   /Users/git/repositories/
Hooks:      /Users/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:        /usr/bin/git
```

and my `gitlab.yml` seems correct

Comment: Are your  `gitlab-shell/bin/check` and `bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production` ok? Your `gitlab.yml` correctly set (as in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3424#issuecomment-24588185?)

Comment: @VonC I have edited my post, and evrything seems fine. Btw, when going to the `testing` gitlab project page, I don't have any file `hierarchy`, I have some doc `Git global setup`, `Create Repository` ...

Comment: @VonC I ran `su git` and then `git` pushed and I get this message  `fatal: 'testing.git' does not appear to be a git repository`

Comment: @VonC, antoher weird thing is that, I started `sidekiq` and I got this message : `Gitlab service started`, but when I run `bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production`, I get `Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... no`

Comment: @VonC I working for a moment to understand the following : when running `gitlab service`, I get `The GitLab Unicorn webserver is not running.
The GitLab Sidekiq job dispatcher with pid 66802 is running.` But  running `bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production`, I get `Checking Sidekiq ... Running? ... no` Do you think it can come from there ?

Comment: It could come from the user under which those processes are running. Make sure you did the installation and the checks with the right user at every step (between `su` (root) and `su git`).

Comment: @VonC ok I get it, first : when I sudo my check, sidekiq is indeed runnning. Second, I changed the remote origin url `git remote set-url origin git@localhost:repositories/root/#{myrepo}.git` and now it works ! How do you think it can from ?

Comment: I have posted a possible explanation for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When running `gitlab` service, I get The GitLab Unicorn webserver is not running.
>   The GitLab Sidekiq job dispatcher with pid 66802 is running.
>   But running `bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production`, I get `Checking Sidekiq ... Running? ... no`

Make sure you did the installation and the checks with the right user at every step (between `su` (root) and `su git`)

The [OP Newben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1275959/newben) [confirms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840478/git-push-failing-on-a-local-gitlab-repo?noredirect=1#comment29529880_19840478):

> when I sudo my check, sidekiq is indeed runnning.

Regarding the repos:

> I changed the remote origin url **`git remote set-url origin git@localhost:repositories/root/#{myrepo}.git`** and now it works !

That comes from a new limitation imposed with **[GitLab 6.0](http://blog.gitlab.org/gitlab-6-dot-0-released/)**:

> From now on a group is not just a directory for projects. It also allows you to add users. After user is added to group – it automatically get access to all existing and new projects inside group.
>   You can also have have multiple owners for a group who can manage members/projects.

See also "[What are the differences between gitlab team and gitlab group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15894795/6309)".

> With this GitLab becomes more group oriented. That is why we no longer support global namespaces. **Project can be part of group or user only**.

Project (your `myrepo.git`) can be part of group or user only (here user account `root`).

Comment: Great, detailed and perfect response response, as usual ;)