# GitLab bare repository import

Tags: git, gitlab

Kindly help me in how to import or push a bare git repository to the GitLab. I'm kind of new to Git & GitLab , so a detailed explanation would be of great help !
I'm using CentOS and GitLab CE edition, version 7.13.1.
Many Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an existing repo you want to import to your GitLab CE server, you can follow: **[Import bare repositories into your GitLab instance](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/import.md)**

The repo is first copied on the server:

```
sudo cp -r /old/git/foo.git /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/new_group/
# Do this once when you are done copying git repositories
sudo chown -R git:git /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/new_group/
```

And then you can register it (still on the GitLab server side):

```
cd /home/git/gitlab
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:import:repos RAILS_ENV=production
```

Now you can [clone it one any client as usual](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/gitlab-basics/command-line-commands.md).

Comment: @babayaga sure: just create a project (http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/gitlab-basics/create-project.html, or https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-gitlab-user-interface-to-manage-projects#initialize-a-project) That will create a bare repo for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, apart from the import option, is there a possibility  to create a bare repo directly in GitLab (web interface)?Also, my bare repo is named as 'foo' and not foo.git , will it be a problem ? I had a look at the instructions and unable to get what is the  "new_group" means,a normal directory?

Comment: @babayaga as I mention, you create a project `newgroup/foo`. That will create the right bare repo foo.git for you on the server side. For group, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15894795/6309. Also see http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/gitlab-basics/create-group.html.

Comment: Really appreciate your inputs, so when I create a project directly in the GitLab webinterface- http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/gitlab-basics/create-project.html , that will be a bare repository not a normal repo with working copy right ?

Comment: @babayaga yes, on the server side, it will create a bare repo. Once you clone it though, you will get a normal non-bare repo on the client side.